# How to pass a collection to mailable laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

How can I send a collection with mailable and organize in the view the items that I have created in a collection within an object?

In my controller I am creating an order like this:

```
$order = Order::create([
            'products' => json_encode(new CartItemCollection($items)),
            'price' => $PartialPrice,
            //other stuff
        ]);
```

In my purchase function, I am sending the email like this:

```
            $pro = $order->products;
            $data = [
                'extra_address' => $order->extra_address,
                'address' => $order->address,
            ];

            Mail::to($check_user->email)->send(new NewPurch($data, $pro));
```

In the configuration of my email I have this:

```
public $data;
public $pro;

public function __construct($data,$pro)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->pro = $pro;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('newpurch')->with(['data' => $this->data])->subject('Thank you');
}
```

And in the view, I receive the data, but I don't know how to access each one

```
@component('mail::message')

Someone want this:

{{$pro}}

@endcomponent
```

The email looks like:
[image]

But I can´t acces as an object `$pro->id` or as a key `$pro['id']`

EDIT:
If I try this:

```
@component('mail::message')

Someone want this:

@foreach($pro->items as $item)
  {{ $item->id }}
@endforeach

@endcomponent
```

Get this error:

> Trying to get property 'items' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/newpurch.blade.php)

And if I try this:

```
 @component('mail::message')

<?php
$deco = json_decode($pro,true);
?>
Someone want this:
  {{ $deco }}

@endcomponent
```

Get this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /app/resources/views/newpurch.blade.php)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

```
public $data;
public $pro;

public function __construct($data, $pro)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->pro = json_decode($pro, true);
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('newpurch')->with(['data' => $this->data])->subject('Thank you');
}
```

And use the foreach since we are now back to a collection instead of a string.

```
@foreach($pro->items as $item)
  {{ $item->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Unless the model is setup to cast `products` to a collection, it would be a string. If it's a string, it first needs to be json_decoded into an array or object, which can then be iterated upon.

Comment: Obviously I could be wrong, but here is what I see: in the `create()` statement, `products` is being set to the json_encoded representation of a collection (a string). Then, you have `$pro = $order->products;`, so now `$pro` is the string. This gets passed into the `NewPurch` constructor which sets the public `$pro` attribute (still a string). This public attribute is then used in the view (still a string). It can only be a collection in the view if there is hidden code that converted it back to a collection, or there is an explicit `$casts` set on the model to cast `products` to `collection`.

Comment: Already try this, and I get this error: Trying to get property 'items' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/newpurch.blade.php), and I do think is becouse of the encode, but dont know where do the json_decode

Comment: Just edit the original question with more info, thank you guys

Comment: @patricus I did not even see that he was parsing. I thought pro was the model collection itself. I will update my answer.